# Why does QGraphicsRectItem object stay at coordinate (0,0) regardless of the coordinates provided explicitly?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm new to Qt5 and tried all the solutions provided online but most of them are from 2011. Am I missing something? It reluctantly stays at (0,0).

File Name: sll.cpp

```
    sll::sll(QWidget *parent) :
        QWidget(parent),
        ui(new Ui::sll)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
    
        scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
        ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
        
        QBrush redbrush(Qt::red);
        QPen blackPen(Qt::black);
        blackPen.setWidth(6);
        
        rect = scene->addRect(500,500,100,50,blackPen,redbrush);
        rect->setPos(-100,-100);
    }
```

The relevant code from sll.h

```
private:
    Ui::sll *ui;


    //Graphics

    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    QGraphicsRectItem *rect;

};
```

The output:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Cause

1. `QGraphicsView` aligns the scene by default in the middle.
2. A graphics scene has dimensions, e.g. `1000x800` px. `QGraphicsView::setSceneRect` or `QGraphicsScene::setSceneRect`, which is equivalent, sets these dimensions. When one of those methods is not used explicitly, Qt determines the dimensions automatically, based on the content's geometry. This leads to the observed from you unintuitive visual behaviour.

### Solution

Add

```
ui->graphicsView->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
ui->graphicsView->setSceneRect(-200, -200, 800, 800);
```

after

```
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
```

### Tip

To avoid possible surprises, do not use the `x` and `y` of the rectangle to set its position, but the `setPos` method of the corresponding `QGraphicsItem`. In other words

```
const QRectF &rect(500, 500, 100, 50);
scene->addRect(rect, blackPen, redbrush);
```

and

```
rect = scene->addRect(0, 0, 100, 50, blackPen, redbrush);
rect->setPos(500, 500);
```

might look as they do the same thing, but it is not like that. Use the second version.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works for me. Could you tell me the significance of graphicsView->setSceneRect as compared to scene->addRect

Comment: `QGraphicsScene::addRect` adds content to the scene. `QGraphicsScene::setSceneRect` sets the scene dimensions. I have edited my answer to explain this better. Please take a look at it.